# Read NMEA sentences in Android 1.6?

Tags: android, gps, nmea

Is there a way to read NMEA sentences in Android 1.6? I see that GpsStatus.NmeaListener requires API level 5 or above, but I am hoping that someone knows a clever way to do this on level 4.

Comment: You can not read NMEA in all devices, it is not supported on few devices like samsung.

Answer (score 1):

No, but you haven't said what you want NMEA for, or what sentences.

I haven't had any success using GpsStatus.NmeaListener to get NMEA on my 2.1 device (which should have a working version). But on the other hand I have written code (in Mintoris Basic, but it's quite simple) to construct three NMEA sentences from the simple GPS data delivered by that restricted run-time. (My purpose is to send the NMEA via Bluetooth; you are welcome to the code if wished.)

Mike.

Comment: I'd like the NMEA sentences for a number of reasons. For instance, I would like to use the HDOP and satellite information from $GPGGA sentences to improve my estimation of fix accuracy. Any code you can share or other ideas you have would be great. Thanks!